# powershell: For loop only loopin´ once instead multiple times

Tags: powershell, csv

i read in a csv files, with multiple lines of information, but my code only executes the first line of the csv content. if i just want to print it out with a
`write-host $dataFilesJS`

it works fine for all contents in the csv file. But if i want to execute the other code its just looping once.

my source code:

```
$CSV= Import-Csv \\test\test.csv -Delimiter ';'

$csvFiles = $CSV 

$csvFiles.Count

for($i=0;$i -lt $csvFiles.count;$i++){

$filepathpdf = $csvFiles.filePathPdf[$i]

$filepathattachments = $csvFiles.filePathAttachments[$i]

$dataFilesJS= $csvFiles.dataFilesJS[$i]

$jsonFile= $csvFiles.jsonFile[$i]

$destinationFolderSave=$csvFiles.destinationFolderSave[$i]

$kategorieName=$csvFiles.kategorieName[$i]

New-Item -Path $destinationFolderSave -ItemType Directory

$foldersaves="\_#_"

$sidepaths = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$sidepathsAttachments= New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

$children = Get-ChildItem $filepathpdf


$childrenAttachments= Get-ChildItem $filepathattachments


$childrensss = Get-ChildItem $filepathpdf/$children
$childrensssAttachments = Get-ChildItem $filepathattachments/$childrenAttachments


for($i=0;$i -le $childrensss.count;$i++){

$sidepaths.add($childrensss[$i])

}


for($i=0;$i -le $childrensssAttachments.count;$i++){

$sidepathsAttachments.add($childrensssAttachments[$i])

}

write-host $sidepathsAttachments

 
for($i=0;$i -lt $childrensss.count;$i++){
$childrenpath= $filepathpdf+"/"+$children+"/"+$sidepaths[$i]

$pdfchildren = Get-ChildItem $childrenpath
write-host $pdfchildren

Copy-Item $childrenpath/*  -Destination $destinationFolderSave -Recurse -force

}

}
```

Comment: [1] DO NOT use the same index variable in all your `for` loops. ///// [2] try using the `foreach` loop instead. it avoids the whole "counter" thing ... [*grin*]

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a little bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me:

```
$CSV= Import-Csv \\test\test.csv -Delimiter ';'

$csvFiles = $CSV 

$csvFiles.Count

foreach($i in $csvFiles){

$filepathpdf = $i.filePathPdf

$filepathattachments = $i.filePathAttachments

$dataFilesJS= $i.dataFilesJS

$jsonFile= $i.jsonFile

$destinationFolderSave=$i.destinationFolderSave

$kategorieName=$i.kategorieName

New-Item -Path $destinationFolderSave -ItemType Directory

$foldersaves="\_#_"

$sidepaths = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$sidepathsAttachments= New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

$children = Get-ChildItem $filepathpdf


$childrenAttachments= Get-ChildItem $filepathattachments


$childrensss = Get-ChildItem $filepathpdf/$children
$childrensssAttachments = Get-ChildItem $filepathattachments/$childrenAttachments


for($i=0;$i -le $childrensss.count;$i++){

$sidepaths.add($childrensss[$i])

}


for($i=0;$i -le $childrensssAttachments.count;$i++){

$sidepathsAttachments.add($childrensssAttachments[$i])

}

write-host $sidepathsAttachments

 
for($i=0;$i -lt $childrensss.count;$i++){
$childrenpath= $filepathpdf+"/"+$children+"/"+$sidepaths[$i]

$pdfchildren = Get-ChildItem $childrenpath
write-host $pdfchildren

Copy-Item $childrenpath/*  -Destination $destinationFolderSave -Recurse -force

}

}
```